# Are there any opensource java libraries for Polyline simplification?

Tags: java, algorithm

Mainly the implementation for Douglas-Peucker algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [JTS](http://www.vividsolutions.com/JTS/JTSHome.htm) (LGPL licence) and it's [`DouglasPeuckerLineSimplifier`](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/simplify/DouglasPeuckerLineSimplifier.html).

(Note it was last updated 2006)

Comment: +1. I will accept the answer after couple of tests

Comment: I get the *"404 - File or directory not found."* error on both links.

Answer (score 4):

You can use https://github.com/hgoebl/simplify-java

Simplification of a 2D-polyline or a 3D-polyline.

- Uses Radial-Distance algorithm (fast) or Douglas-Peucker (high quality) algorithm
- Port of mourner / simplify-js, a High-performance JavaScript 2D/3D polyline simplification library by Vladimir Agafonkin
- Can handle arbitrary objects carrying coordinates (2D, 3D) either by
  implementing an interface or by providing a helper extracting the
  coordinates
- Leaves the objects untouched, just creates a new array referencing
  the simplified points
- requires Java 5
- Maven Build
- JUnit-tested, 94% lines covered, reference data is created by "original" JavaScript implementation (Version 1.1.0)

Comment: I have an issue with trying to implement your library code. Can you shed some light? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010298/simplify-java-by

Comment: I'll help you, one moment please...